# Editing image-based subtitles

Tags: subtitles

[DVD and Blu-ray discs use image-based subtitles](https://wiki.videolan.org/Subtitles/#Subtitles_support_in_VLC) — I've ripped my entire collection and text can't be edited in any way.

Both VLC and MPC-HC have no control over subtitle appearance in these rips. Choosing font and size in the media player options is ignored and even the text location can't be changed.

Additionally, since English-language subtitles are universally created for the deaf and hearing impaired (SDH) I could easily remove marked sound effects which are typically enclosed with square brackets, (`[]`).

Comment: When playing the disks in question in their original format, do you get a choice of whether to view or not view the subtitles? How did you rip the videos? What settings?

Comment: @music2myear: Subtitles can be disabled or enabled, of course. I ripped using MakeMKV. I know that picture-based subtitles can be converted into text, but I'm looking for an easier way to modify.

Comment: This search https://www.google.com/search?q=ocr+on+image+based+subtitles shows me these results https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284005/convert-image-based-subtitle-to-text-based-subtitle-inside-mkv-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230831/detect-subtitle-from-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Subtitle Edit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit) ([homepage](http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit/)) is capable of converting image-based subtitles to plain text (optical character recognition) and can fix common conversion-errors in the process. There's a feature to remove text for hearing impaired as well.

[image: fix common errors]

[image: remove text for hearing impaired]

features:

> Create/adjust/sync/translate subtitle lines
>
> Convert
>   between SubRib, MicroDVD, Advanced Sub Station Alpha,  Sub Station
>   Alpha, D-Cinema, SAMI, youtube sbv, and many more (**200+ different
>   formats!**)
>
> Cool **audio visualizer** control - can
>   display wave form and/or spectrogram
>
> Video player uses
>   DirectShow, [VLC media
>   player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), or [MPlayer](http://www.mplayer2.org/)
>
> **Visually sync**/adjust a subtitle (start/end position and
>   speed)
>
> Auto Translation via Google translate
>
> Rip
>   subtitles from a (decrypted) dvd
>
> Import and OCR VobSub
>   sub/idx binary subtitles
>
> Import and OCR Blu-ray .sup files -
>   bd sup reading is based on Java code from BDSup2Sub by
>   0xdeadbeef)
>
> Can open subtitles embedded inside matroska files
>
> Can open
>   subtitles (text, closed captions, vobsub) embedded inside mp4/mv4
>   files
>
> Can open/OCR XSub subtitles embedded inside divx/avi
>   files
>
> Can open/OCR DVB subtitles embedded inside .ts
>   (Transport Stream) files
>
> Can open/OCR Blu-ray subtitles
>   embedded inside .m2ts (Transport Stream) files
>
> Can read and
>   write both **UTF-8 and other unicode files** and ANSI (support for
>   all languages/encodings on the pc!)
>
> Sync: Show texts
>   earlier/later + point synchronization + synchronization via other
>   subtitle
>
> Merge/split subtitles
>
> Adjust display
>   time
>
> **Fix common errors wizard**
>
> Spell
>   checking via Open
>   Office dictionaries/NHunspell (many
>   dictionaries available)
>
> **Remove text for hear impaired
>   (HI)**
>
> Renumbering
>
> Swedish to Danish translation
>   built-in (via [Multi Translator
>   Online](/MultiTranslator/))
>
> Effects: Typewriter and karaoke
>
> History/undo manager (Undo=Ctrl+z, Redo=Ctrl+y)
>
> Compare
>   subtitles
>
> Multiple search and replace
>
> Change
>   casing using names dictionary
>
> Merge short lines/split long
>   lines
>
> Export to PNG images (+bdn xml), Adobe Encore FAB
>   image script, VobSub, Blu-ray sup, EBU stl, PAC, and plain text

Comment: The program appears to be Windows-only, built in C#.

Comment: Subtitle Edit is Linux compatible, launch it with `mono SubtitleEdit.exe`. To install mono on Ubuntu use `apt install mono-complete`. SubEdit will even use ffmpeg and such from your system.

Comment: Is there any alternative for osx ? `mono ~/Downloads/SE366/SubtitleEdit.exe` → `WARNING: The Carbon driver has not been ported to 64bits, and very few parts of Windows.Forms will work properly, or at all`, `[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException`